# Lower Z index of view in storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I created a tab bar with `UIView` in the storyboard, and after that I decided to add a `UIImageView` under the tab bar view. The image must be at the bottom, behind the tab bar, but the image view overlaps my tab bar. How do I lower my image view's z-index to fix the problem?

I've already tried moving the tab bar up in the Document Outline:

[image: Screenshot of document outline]

Pictures for understanding:

[image: Image view and tab bar next to each other]

[image: Image view overlaps tab bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the Document Outline is opened in your storyboard. It's the icon at the bottom-left of your screen.

[image: Button at bottom-left of screen "Show Document Outline"]

Then just drag the image view before the tab bar. This will bring it to the bottom.

[image: Image is ordered before the tab bar]

Comment: Already tried, not working.

Comment: @ZapDojin hmm, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70806965/edit) your question to include an image of your Document Outline?

Comment: edited my question, you can check.

Comment: @ZapDojin notice how your image is *after* the tab bar. The image needs to be *before* the tab bar. The order of the document outline is lowest -> highest, which might be the opposite of what you expect.